# Can I use these brackets to make wall mounted bookshelves?

Tags: shelving

I have a fairly small home office and I also have several hundred books that I'd like to keep in my office. Because of the limited floor space I want to avoid any type of shelving that sits on the floor. I'd like to hang 4 or 5 6' shelves starting at around 4 feet up the wall.

I plan on spanning the 6' with construction grade 2x10s and for brackets I'd like to use these [7" Black Heavy-Duty Shelf Brackets](https://www.menards.com/main/building-materials/shelves-shelving-units/shelving-hardware-accessories/7-black-heavy-duty-shelf-bracket/p-1444428703976-c-12645.htm?tid=-5022698900832895848).

[image]

Each pair of these brackets can hold up to 1000 pounds, and I plan on using three per shelf, anchored to the studs.

Each bracket is only 7" deep, is it acceptable to use 2x10s with these brackets? Each shelf would be cantilevered about 2.25".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2x10s will be fine with those brackets. The [sagulator](http://www.woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/) calculates about an 1/8" sag over the 6' span with a 500lb load and 2 brackets (anchored at sides), which is plenty acceptable - and 500lb is probably an overestimation for a single shelf. Shelving brackets are not intended to span the entire depth of the shelf either, but make sure the brackets are secured to the underside of the shelf properly

Comment: I agree, and would only add that suitable attachment to the wall framing is critical. Use 1/4" or 5/16" lag screws as will fit the bracket holes, and be sure they penetrate at least 2" into the framing. Pilot slightly smaller than the shank of the screw (inside thread diameter) to improve hold and prevent splitting.

Comment: Thanks for these additional tips. Do you think a structural screw (Spax, GRK, etc) could be used as a replacement for lag screws in this application?